# YOLO custom loss using keras

Tags: python, keras, loss-function

I am trying to solve a similar problem like YOLO, except by the fact that my boxes are rotated. Thus I need to add a 6th parameter to account for theta/rotation. I only have one class. My tensors are 16x16x6

This implementation does not seem to work. My loss is always the same regardless of network architecture or epoch. After many changes I am deeply convinced my loss calculation is wrong

```
def my_loss(y_true,y_pred):

# 0,prob / 1,x /2,y/3,a/4,b/5,theta
#params["w_l"]=[5.0,0.5]
#m1=labels[...,5] > 0
#m2=labels[...,5] < 0
#labels[m1][...,5]/=360
#labels[m2][...,5]=(labels[m2][...,5]+360)/360

    lambda_coord=y_true[...,0]*params["w_l"][0]
    lambda_noobj=-(y_true[...,0] -1.0)*params["w_l"][1]

    ly=K.sum(K.square(y_pred[...,1]-y_true[...,1])*lambda_coord)
    lx=K.sum(K.square(y_pred[...,2]-y_true[...,2])*lambda_coord)
    lt=K.sum(K.square(y_pred[...,5]-y_true[...,5])*lambda_coord)
    la=K.sum(K.square(K.sqrt(y_pred[...,3])-K.sqrt(y_true[...,3]))*lambda_coord)
    lb=K.sum(K.square(K.sqrt(y_pred[...,4])-K.sqrt(y_true[...,4]))*lambda_coord)
    lp=K.sum(K.square(y_true[...,0]-y_pred[...,0])*lambda_noobj)
    return ly+lx+lt+la+lb+lp
```

My label array contains probability/y/x/a/b/theta.
Loss coming from positives (coordinates/size/theta) are multiplied by a factor, as to reinforce their losses on the total loss, while the probability loss for Negatives is reduced by a factor as to lower their influence.

Any advise of improvement or hind at what is wrong ?

Thanks

JC

Answer (score 0):

I edited my question in order for my response to make sense. The issue with my loss calculation was not related to my implementation but to how I was setting up my labels.

A box rotated on 90 degrees or -90 degrees is essentially the same box due to symmetry. Both answers are true which make the theta term of my loss to never decrease.

As the range of theta, out of opencv rotatedbox, was eventually -90,90, making my labels = (labels +90)/180  solved my convergence issues.

hope this helps.